# How to Search for text in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Please I need to write a query to search for a text from one columns in all cells of a column.

For example:

[image]

I need to pick every text from column B cells and try to find it in column A cells. if found do something. Can you help me?. This will be used for a thousand of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put this in C1 and copy it down:

```
=iferror(if(match(B1,A:A,0)>0,"Do Something",""))
```

Here is a link to my test spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W65pNPqqYA1fmvjQyferqOHzXbSyRIOV2XvF6MdMBmE/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Ed Nelson tks! This returning an error. `=iferror(if(match(B1,A:A,1)>0,"Do Something",""))`  **Formula Parsing Error**

Comment: @RodrigoRocha See link to test sheet in answer.

Comment: Ed Nelson I am getting an error using exactly the same formula that you typed. Can you show me in my google sheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8ypdvoQ5TR__7OqEq9cozFQo6IOLmgEP00Vv90_g9w/edit?usp=sharing   I gave edit permissions. The data I am working on are CPFs (brazilian identification document). All CPFs are fake.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet. It is not your number formats. I added your data to the sample sheet I shared (Sheet2) and my formula still works. I generally find replacing "," with ";" fixes formulas with language differences. That did not work. I will let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: If that works for you, please approve the answer. Thanks.